# How to create infinte scroll in wordpress for blog and custom post type

Tags: infinite-scroll

How to create infinite scroll in wordpress for blog and custom post type. I have tried jetpack infinite scroll but its not working on custom wordpress page template for custom post type. I looked at this tutorial but it seems old

http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-create-infinite-scroll-pagination--wp-24873

And also looked this one https://github.com/infinite-scroll/infinite-scroll
but this project is no longer maintained.

Please tell me or recommend some new tutorials that are compatible with Wordpress 4.5 for create infinte scroll.

Thanks

Comment: maybe try ajax load more plugin.

Comment: Thanks majick I am creating Theme that's why need to create it without plugin.

Comment: Sorry, but this is a _very_ broad and [_widely_ discussed](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/search?q=infinite+scroll) problem - there is no "one size fits all" solution. If you're coding a theme, you should be sufficient in PHP/JavaScript to roll your own. If you get stuck with something in particular, _then_ come back with your code and we'll be happy to help.

Comment: here's a good walkthru: https://rudrastyh.com/wordpress/load-more-posts-ajax.html ajax-loadmore plugin is alright, but has code-bloat in the ajax generated output.

Comment: i need to know how we add infinite scroll to load pages not posts. is there ant way kindly guide me. i had the load post code for my website but i want to load pages on scroll or button click.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to define a new loop function for the Custom Post Type to pass to the `render` parameter.

As in the example from https://jetpack.com/support/infinite-scroll/

```
/**
 * Add theme support for infinity scroll
 */
function twenty_ten_infinite_scroll_init() {
    add_theme_support( 'infinite-scroll', array(
        'container' => 'content',
        'render'    => 'twenty_ten_infinite_scroll_render',
        'footer'    => 'wrapper',
    ) );
}
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'twenty_ten_infinite_scroll_init' );

/**
 * Set the code to be rendered on for calling posts,
 * hooked to template parts when possible.
 *
 * Note: must define a loop.
 */
function twenty_ten_infinite_scroll_render() {
    get_template_part( 'loop' );
}
```

As you can see you can call a template part within that function to generate the next load of posts to be displayed (Infinite Scroll will update the query for you so you simply need a loop template.)